# Best way to efficiently load large lists

Tags: android, performance

My question is: how is it possible to load (only once, when the user launches the app) a large listview.

For example, an SMS app.

As soon as the app is opened, the app will fetch for all SMS in the phone's memory and show them in a ListView. But how can you do it without disturbing the user or impacting the performance ?

An ***ASyncTask*** looking for all the conversations while the user is still staring at the top ? What if he has more than 100000 SMS ? Should I restrict it to a number and when the user reaches a certain point then load the rest ?
For a "research in your messages" function, do I need to have ALL the SMS loaded for easy access or search in the phone's memory for easy storage?

Finally, I always wondered how did famous chat apps handle that, and I'm really curious what are the solutions.

Thanks for your help,

Ysjanati.

**EDIT:** Well, it's true that I was asking way too many questions for not much, I'll attempt to rectify this.
First, I tried many things, like :

- loading messages bit by bit while the user scrolls through the list
- a big loading at the beginning of the instance
- even making a page-by-page model with a big "load more" button

The thing about databases is that if we're talking about SMS, there is already an intern database within the phone containing all the data I need. You don't want to forget that other apps may manipulate this DB without my app's permission; it means we need constant syncing between the phone's native DB and my custom one. What do you sugger ?

Once again, thanks for all of your answers.

Comment: You need to break your question down into manageable pieces. Try thinking from the perspective of the reader who most likely has better things to do than answer questions on StackOverflow. Positing multiple questions that do not have a clear definitive answer sever only to remind the person (myself) of all the things I should be doing! The best way to get answers is to show what you have tried and where it has specifically gone wrong.

Comment: use `[Simple]CursorAdapter` + `Loaders` framework + `SMS ContentProvider` combo

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggest to implement in my answer. After that step you might want to implement "paging", like loading only 50-100 sms at a time, and only load more when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom, or is approaching it. Using a Loader makes the reloading automatic when the data you display changes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the messages or whaterver items in a local SQLite database on the phone, and then load them into the list via a ContentProvider, in certain batches, eg. 100 at a time. This way you can also search between them, by writing SQL queries, and change the list items to the ones returned by the query.

Android has its own concept around it called Loader.
See the documentation about Loaders [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

To use a loader you first have to tell the system that you ant to initialize a loader, usually in your onCreate method if you are using an Activity, like this:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Then the system will call the onCreateLoader callback in which you have to specify how you want to load the content. Eg. load all the conacts with a phone number in alphabetical order:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
// pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
// currently loading.
Uri baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI

// Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
// creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
        + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
        + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
        CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

}

And when the system ran your query then put the results in your adapter so your list items change, showing the results of your query.

```
// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing
    // the old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

The same basic steps apply to any other kind of loader. You dont necessarily have to use a CursorLoader, you can come up with your own implementations to reflect your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Always query databases in another thread.  AsyncTask is an option, among other options.  If you think your dataset might be too large to fit in memory, you might also want to consider paging your results and dynamically adjusting the window of a available items to adjust as the user is scrolling the view.

Comment: RecyclerView list class loads list items dynamically upon scrolling try using this class combined possibly  with worker threads. If the list is very large and you need to execute code upon completion you can use the android.os.Handler class